# WebGL - render depth to fbo texture does not work

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

For a post processing shader, I need the color and the depth buffer of my framebuffer. Accessing the colorbuffer works fine but I have problems creating the depthbuffer. I always get an INVALID_ENUM error when trying to use texImage2D for the depth texture:

```
WebGL error INVALID_ENUM in texImage2D(TEXTURE_2D, 0, DEPTH_COMPONENT16, 1536, 502, 0, DEPTH_COMPONENT, UNSIGNED_BYTE, null)
```

using a renderbuffer instead of a texture works but I want depth in a texture so I can pass it to a shader.

framebuffer with depth texture code:

```
Framebuffer.prototype.initBufferStuffTexture = function(width, height){
    if(this.width == width && this.height == height){
        return;
    }

    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

    // remove existing buffers
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
    if(this.texture != null){
        gl.deleteTexture(this.texture.glid);
        this.texture = null;
    }
    if(this.renderbuffer != null){
        gl.deleteRenderbuffer(this.renderbuffer);
        this.renderbuffer = null;
    }
    if(this.framebuffer != null){
        gl.deleteFramebuffer(this.framebuffer);
        this.framebuffer = null;
    }

    // create new buffers
    this.framebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
    this.texture = new Texture();
    this.texture.glid = gl.createTexture();
    this.depth = new Texture();
    this.depth.glid = gl.createTexture();

    // framebuffer
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, this.framebuffer);
    this.framebuffer.width = width;
    this.framebuffer.height = height;

    // colorbuffer
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.texture.glid);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, this.framebuffer.width, this.framebuffer.height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

    // depthbuffer
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.depth.glid);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT16, this.framebuffer.width, this.framebuffer.height, 0, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

    // assemble buffers
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.texture.glid, 0);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.depth.glid, 0);

    this.checkBuffer();

    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
    gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, null);
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The OpenGL ES 2.0 specification (against which WebGL was specified) doesn't list `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT` (or any of its sized versions) as a valid texture internal format, so it seems not to support depth textures and as the WebGL specification doesn't state anywhere that it behaves differently, it also doesn't support depth textures.

But maybe this [link](http://www.devmaster.net/forums/showthread.php?t=17419) is of help, where depth txtures are emulated in WebGL by packing the depth value into a standard rgba texture.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. If I understood that right, the only way to get depth info is to add another pass that renders the whole scene into a rgba texture using a shader that outputs depth values as rgba values.

I guess I have to ditch the post processing. Rendering the scene just once takes too long, I can't efford to render it twice. It's made up of a few million points.

Comment: @Markus You might also use multiple render targets (rendering into an FBO with multiple color attachments, and therefore writing our multiple colors from the fragment shader), but I don't know how far this is supported in WebGL.

Comment: Posts about mrts say it's not possible and the spec only defines "COLOR_ATTACHMENT0". What a pitty, that'd have been a nice feature too.

Comment: WEBKIT_WEBGL_depth_texture extension is now widely supported

Comment: The link is 404. pls update